# Variables in preprocessor IFs not found ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper

```
class a
{
   private int num;
   private Person p;
    ....
   public int SomeMethod()
  {
    #IF someCondition
     p = new Person();
     num = 2;
     p.Legs = num;
  } 
}
```

Resharper says here that both of the fields are not being used. Which is false, i.e. depends on the condition. How can I avoid this?

I searched for similar questions, found some but still didn't manage to understand how to fix this problem. So please, even if this question is duplicate, at least tell me how can I fix it exactly.

Comment: because it is not necessary that everytime it goes in ``if`` block

Comment: Why won't you wrap the declaration of the fields with the `#IF condition` as well?

Comment: @haim770 nice question, I will consider this approach from now on. For now I won't change anything because of too many dependencies(kind of don't feel like touching stuff in order not to search for stupid bugs and so on). Anyway thanks for the comment, will take it into consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Resharper trying to be helpful,
(Originally said comments should be around the #IF block, this is incorrect)

If you surround your variable declaration with the following comments then it will tell Resharper to exclude this test during it's analysis of this code block.

```
// ReSharper disable UnusedVariable.Compiler
        private int num;
        private Person p;
// ReSharper restore UnusedVariable.Compiler
```

Comment: My ReSharper 8 is suppressing the warning by surrounding the declaration block with: `#pragma warning disable 169`, and `#pragma warning restore 169`.

Comment: You're putting the `#pragma` in the wrong place. You need to wrap the fields declaration block, not its usage.

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked. Thanks man, just I'm curious why Pheonyx's answer didn't work for me? Did I do anything wrong there as well?

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov, it could just a re-sharper version issue that it didn't work. That was the code that resharper put into my quick test block to disable the warning. Haim770 was correct, it should be around the declaration of the variables and not the If condition.

Comment: @Pheonyx what version are you using?

Comment: @VentsislavMarinov Resharper 8.2.3, in Visual Studio Professional 2013.

Comment: Yeah, most likely it's from the version. I'm using 8.1.23 with VS Ultimate 2013.

Comment: // ReSharper disable UnusedField.Compiler

            private int disabledDisks;

// ReSharper restore UnusedField.Compile

This is the case with my version, so obviously it depends on the version of ReSharper very much. So, should I close or delete this question? I think it would be best to close it, apparently it's kind of ambiguous.

Comment: It appears that I can't do anything to close it but still I'm not going to delete it. I'm open to suggestions.